# How to return all records present in MongoDb if query is null?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have the following endpoint returning all the courses found in Db by default. I want to change it so that when req.query.class is empty it returns all records otherwise returns records conditionally.

```
router.get('/allcourses', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    const studentclass = req.query.class;
    Course.find().select({ coursename: 1 }).select({ class: 1 }).select({ board: 1 }).select({ coursedescription: 1 }).then((data) => {
        res.status(200).json({
            courses: data
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(503).json({
            message: 'Cannot retreive courses at this moment, try again later!'
        })
    })
})
```

I cannot figure out how to use studentclass variable.

If I do `Course.find({class:studentclass}).select({ coursename: 1 }).select({ class: 1 }).select({ board: 1 }).select({ coursedescription: 1 })` it returns empty when req.query.class is empty (of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define an empty `filter` object and set the `class` property depending on the existence of the `req.query.class` variable:

```
const filter = {};
if(req.query.class) {
    filter.class = req.query.class;
}

Course.find(filter).select(...)
```

Note that this would not set `class` in the filter if `req.query.class` yielded an empty string (i.e. `""`), due to the JavaScript's truthy evaluation of a string. If you want to set the filter in that case, you need to explicitly check if the value is not `undefined`:

```
if(typeof req.query.class !== 'undefined') { ... }
```

Comment: Works like a absolute charm, thank you. Probably should brush up my basic JavaScript lol

Answer (score 1):

We can construct a query by filtering out undefined properties, this will work when there are multiple fields in the query as well

```
const omitUndefined = (obj = {}) => Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((result, [key, value]) => 
    ({ ...result, ...(typeof value !== "undefined" && { [key]: value }) }) ,
  {})

Course.find(omitUndefined({ class: req.query.class })).select(...)
/*
This will work for multiple fields, if all fields are undefined you will end up with an empty query object
Course.find(omitUndefined({ class: req.query.class, board: req.query.board })).select(...)
*/
```

Comment: i would take this approach when I'd be expecting multiple filters, but the answer by @eol solves my current problem the best. Thank you, though. (: